# SubscribeController.m:63 SUPPersistenceException: SUPPersistenceException from synchronize:Message: Failure occurred while executing user supplie

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using SUP sample app for Sup2.1.3 but after replacing generated code it id giving following error:

> [SubscribeController.m:63] SUPPersistenceException:
>   SUPPersistenceException from synchronize: -- SUPSynchronizeException:
>   Sync failed: -857 (ERROR) %1:[-10225] Message: Failure occurred while
>   executing user supplie

Can anyone know why this exception is coming and how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was working on Same problem 
When I was using Old MBO app was running good..
but as soon as made changes in MBO app started giving above error..

Problem got Solved When I got properly developed and deployed MBO.

Comment: Hi i am also facing the same.. I think if you use personalization keys then we are having this error. What key your keeping in the personalization such as client or transient.. Please help me.. I struck to it..

Comment: Hi When I am using runtime data source credential. In that, I am using default personalization keys username and password.. I am getting the above error. i am using transient key only.. Thanks in advance